# Travis: How to use variables configured through repo settings in builds triggered by forks?

Tags: testing, github, travis-ci, test-environments

Some tests from suite use credentials which I've configured through repo settings on Travis. Although these are available only to pull requests from original repos - not forks (according to [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings)).

How do I make those tests pass even on pull requests from forks? Do I have to skip those or there's some other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this is something that bothers other developers too https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1946

I guess problem could be solved with some scripting:

```
if $secret_env.present?
  run_all_tests
else
  run_tests_which_dont_require_secret_env
end
```

Another workaround could be to ask project owner to provide you with credentials you would use to setup your fork.